# Fragment option in the Support Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

What are the various layouts that are created when a developer utilizes the Fragment option in the Android Design Support Library?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  A Fragment can hold any layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments (from the support library or not) support all widgets and layout components that Activities can

Nothing is "created" extra when you define a Fragment outside of the Fragment itself